# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toMillis')

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, post

I understand that in most cases this is due to a syntax error, but that does not appear to be the case (at least in my definitely not good perspective).

When I ctrl F, 'toMillis' is not a word in any of my pages. I am unsure what could be causing this.

The error triggers when I use jquery to post/send to server and get a response, but I am using the same syntax and format here as in other scenarios where it does indeed work without error.

Client side js code:

```
 var currD = stampCurrentDate();
   var a = { currentChatUID: currentChatUID, message: message, Date: currD};
          $.post('/sendNewMessage', a, function (data, status) {
                   var isError = data.Error;
                    if(isError == "yes") {
                      displayErrorMessage("Error Sending Message");
                        id('chatroom_body').style.borderColor = "red";
                        setTimeout(function() { id('chatroom_body').style.borderColor = "#242F36"; }, 3000);
                      return;
                    }
            console.log("Message Successfully Sent");
            const chat = findChatByUID(chats, currentChatUID); console.log(chat);
            console.log(chat.user2Messages);
            chat.lastSentDate = stampCurrentDate(); chat.user2Messages.push(new Message(stampCurrentDate(), message, 2));
            console.log(chat.user2Messages);
            console.log(chats);
            getChatProfilePictures(getChatsWOProfile());
  
         });
```

Server(express):

```
app.post('/sendNewMessage', function(req, res) {
  var currentChatUID = req.body.currentChatUID;
  var message = req.body.message;
  var Date = req.body.Date;
    db.collection("Messaging").doc(currentChatUID).update({
    User2Messages: db.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({Message: message, Date: Date, Read: false}),
        Last: Date,    
  }).then(() => {
     res.send({juice:"juice"});
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    var dataToSend = {Error:"yes"};
    res.json(dataToSend);   
  })
})
```

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

student messaging line 325 is

```
     $.post('/sendNewMessage', a, function (data, status) {
```

line 368 is just calling the function that has the first client side code chunk above.

Comment: Can you post the `stampCurrentDate` function?

Comment: function stampCurrentDate() {
  const date = new Date();
  return firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}

Comment: Oh, interesting. I didn't realize Date was orange in stack overflow's code syntax. Weird indeed.

Comment: oh wait thats because its a function.

Comment: Try to declare your `Date` body parameter as `date`

Comment: No change. Hmm, it says ajax is used, but I only see jquery here?